# Validation of child object

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, jquery-validate

I have an object that contains a child object. eg.

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Car Car { get; set; }
 }

 public class Car
 {
     public int CarId{get;set;
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string Year { get; set; }
 }
```

Then on my Razor view i use a DropDownlistFor, with the list of cars that the user can select. I bind the Dropdownlist like

```
    @Html.LocalLabelFor(m => m.Person.Car)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Person.Car, new SelectList(Model.Cars, "CarID, "Name"), "Select")
```

When the user does not select a car, then the jquery validation still validates the CarId as not being selected. The car object must be nullable.

I know I can get around this by creating a flat viewmodel.

Is there any other way to make the car optional on the form ?

Comment: For now until this post can provide another answer I created the viewmodel. Would be cool if there is alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Just make CarId nullable:

```
public class Car
 {
     public int? CarId { get; set };
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string Year { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: That is more of a hack than a solution, I did think about it, but that means on my "Car" edit view, the CarId can be set as null. This is just a simple example, in the app, I have many objects like this, and setting the Id as nullable does not feel right.

Comment: @Captain0 I don't understand, you don't want CarId to be nullable and that time you want to leave it blank on view side. If you leave it empty, null value must be inserted, for this, variable must be nullable.

Answer (score 0):

Clear the error from the model state in the controller action

For ex.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(Person person)
{
      if (person.Car != null && person.Car.CarId == 0)
      {
        if (ModelState.ContainsKey("Car.CarId"))
          ModelState["Car.CarId"].Errors.Clear();
      }

      return View();
}
```

Comment: The valdation happens client side, before the submit.